# how to load jsp pages into the same jsp page according to the option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a drop down menu in the top section of my web app page. When I select any option from the list , the rest of the section should load appropriately. when I select any other option the existing section should be refreshed and the selected options page must be loaded.
Note that the top section since its menu it should not be refreshed.
How can I do this?
I've tried using I-Frame and Ajax but was able to load only one option.

Here's the code

```
script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[ $(document).ready(function(){ $('#myIframe').attr('src','../file.jsp'); }); //]]>
</script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <p>welcome to stack</p>
   <input type="button" id="pageId" value="load page" />
    <div id="pageId"> 
        <iframe src="" id="myIframe" frameborder="1" width="1000" height="510"></iframe> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to show some code

Comment: can u show your ajax code please?

Comment: Thanks for your response....script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#myIframe').attr('src','../file.jsp');
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>welcome to stack</p>
<input type="button" id="pageId" value="load page" />
<div id="pageId">
    <iframe src="" id="myIframe" frameborder="1" width="1000" height="510"></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery` and `jsp`:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select_box_id").change(function () {
        var checked = $(this).val();
        $("#content").html('<%@ include file="/'+checked+'.jsp" %>');
    });
})

// you must have 2 jsp files each with appropriate names of radion buttons value
// you can also use AJAX requests
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select id="select_box_id">
        <option value="something"></option>
    </select>
    <div id="content"></div>
 </div>
```